# How to fix error to fill DropDown Button with Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fill a Dropdown Button with Firestore and i can get the data but i can't put it on the dropdown.

I had already identified the problem and it's the item list of the DropDown Button but i don't understand what is happening.

When i put the valor null on 'items' it works (doesn't show error) but doesn't show anything (obviously).

Here is my code.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: Firestore.instance
              .collection('usuarios/$id/ubications')
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              const Text("Error");
            } else {
              List<DropdownMenuItem> ubicationItems = [];
              print(snapshot.data.documents.length);
              for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.documents.length; i++) {
                DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data.documents[i];
                //_accountType.add(snap['ubication']);
                ubicationItems.add(DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: Text(
                    snap['ubication'],
                  ),
                  value: "${snap['ubication']}",
                ));
              }
              print(ubicationItems.length); //it has the data
              return Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  DropdownButton(
                    items: ubicationItems,
                    onChanged: (selectedType) {
                      print('$selectedType');
                      setState(() {
                        selectedType = selectedUbication;
                      });
                    },
                    value: selectedUbication,
                    isExpanded: true,
                    hint: new Text("ubication"),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
          }),
```

This is the error:
I/flutter (14877): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 609 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null || items.where((DropdownMenuItem item) => item.value == value).length == 1': is not true.

i used this example like guide: https://github.com/whatsupcoders/FlutterDropDown/blob/master/lib/main.dart

I hope someone can help me, thanks.

Comment: Which one is line 609 ? And where do  you set the value of `selectedUbication`?

Comment: I don't have the line 609, and i had declared selectedUbication in the class and the valor change in the function setState()

Comment: What's the output of print(selectedUbication) ? The assertion tells you either items == null, empty or value == null or the selected item's length == 1 i believe.

Comment: The problem was that i had declared the variable selectedUbication like a String and i changed it to var and works now!

Comment: Great! Consider answering and accepting your own question tho, so other people know you fixed it or can find an answer if they have the same problem